# django haystack solr: index file not being created

Tags: solr, django-haystack

solr is not able to create index, get following error:

```
All documents removed.
Indexing 100 notes.
Failed to add documents to Solr: [Reason: None]
<html><head><meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
<title>Error 404 NOT_FOUND</title></head><body><h2>HTTP ERROR 404</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /solr/boatsite/update/. Reason:<pre>    NOT_FOUND</pre></p>
<hr /><i><small>Powered by    Jetty://</small></i>
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Answer is in Beta 2.0.0 docs under trouble shooting.  Was using a bad URL in settings.py for HAYSTACK CONNECTIONS.  Docs suggest test URL in browser if you get this error.  I was trying http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/mysite ---should have been using http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr